# How to make Highchart responsive in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to make my highchart responsive, however i do not know how to adjust my chart to be responsive. My understanding is to make the width 100%, however i got an error when i changed the Width = 100%.

Also tried putting Style (Width : 100%), and it does not work still. 
This charting is done on the controller which will be displayed on the view page of dashboard.

Any one know how to edit this code to make it work ?

```
 Highcharts chart4 = new Highcharts("chart4")
        .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column,
          Width = 550,
          Height = 400,
       })
```

Comment: Instead of setting the size in chart option, do that in CSS of container. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g1qm6upw/

Comment: This is what I do as well. Now, if you needed to use the current width and/or height to adjust any of the settings in your responsive chart, you can grab the properties of your container as such: `$('#container').height()` and `$('#container').width()`.